# Recurring Job with delay time

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, hangfire, recurring

I'm using Hangfire version "1.6.8". I want create recurring job with Cron.Daily after certain DateTime . Is that possible to create recurring job with delay time ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use Cron.Daily(time.Hours, time.Minutes); -to make daily job with specific time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of any particularly clean way of doing this.

You could explore the avenue of using a hangfire Scheduled job to create the RecurringJob:

```
new BackgroundJobClient().Schedule(() => Hangfire.RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World"), Cron.Daily()), startDateTime)
```

Which could be set to run the Scheduled job shortly before the first expected run time of the Recurring Job, and thus hangfire runs the schedule and creates the job itself. I haven't actually ever tried to do this, so please do test it (and let me know how it goes).

Comment: I see you've accepted my answer, does that mean that this worked? How did it go? Do you have any more specific implementation details for anyone who follows?

Comment: I tried that and I am getting that exception: System.NotSupportedException: 'Anonymous functions, delegates and lambda expressions aren't supported in job method parameters: it's very hard to serialize them and all their scope in general.'

Comment: @adam.bielasty I have this problem too!

Answer (score 0):

From the [HangFire docs](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html), you can use [CRON expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression). They are a little difficult to pick up initially, but once you get the hang of the structure, you will be able to do everything you're looking for. Do note, these are **exact** times, and there is no "whenever you feel like it after this time." Tell it when you want it to run.

For example, if you want it to run every day at 2 PM:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("Powerful!"), "0 14 * * *");
```

- `0`: 0 minutes
- `14`: 2PM (14:00 hours)
- `*`: Every day of the month
- `*`: Every month of the year
- `*`: Every day of the week.

Comment: Think the OP was looking for something like "do every day at 2pm... *starting after x days' time*".  No CRON expression for that kind of thing, sadly, hence the idea of scheduling a meta-job (do after x days' time) the regular job (every day at 2pm).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
  {
                BackgroundJob.Schedule(
                    () => RunJob(),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
                    );
  }



    public static void RunJob()
    {
       using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
       {
         RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World123"), "* * * * *");
                
      }
    }
```